# How to convert 3D array to a list of 2D arrays in python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, svd

I want to convert a 3D array (say size = 3x3x4) to a list of 3 (3x4) arrays.
The 3D Array **A** in the *else* block is not the same type as in the *if* block.

I tried tolist() function, but it converts the 3D array to a list of lists, which is not desired.

```
X = np.random.randn(3, 3, 3)
for R in range(1,10):
    N = len(X.shape) 
    B = ()
    C = []

    for i in range(N):
        B += svd(X[i])
        C.append(B[3*i])
        
    C = np.array(C)
    if R <= np.shape(C)[2]:
        A = C[:,:,:R]
    else:
        A = np.concatenate((C[:,:,:np.shape(C)[2]],np.zeros((3,3,1))),axis=2)
```

Ideally, `A = [np.random.randn(In, R) for In in X.shape]`.
But I am modifying this step by assigning left singular vectors of **X** to **A**.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What can list do for you that numpy can't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A numpy array is an iterable, you you can easily convert it to a list:

```
lst = list(A)
```

Demo:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
>>> arr
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
>>> list(arr)
[array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]]), array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert 3D array to list of 2D arrays, just use `list`:

```
X = np.random.randn(3, 3, 3)
list(X)
```